# All other httpClient executions need to wait other fail execution to fail first before executed?

Tags: android, httpclient

I have following code:

**HttpHelper**

```
public class HttpHelper {
    public HttpEntity httpGet(String url){
        HttpClient httpclient = Client.getThreadSafeClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Examine the response status
            Log.d(TAG, "Response status: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            return entity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client {
    public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {   
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();

        HttpParams httpParameters = client.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient(
            new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters,
                mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), httpParameters);

        return client;
    } 
}
```

I invoke it by using this code:

```
HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
HttpEntity entity = httpHelper.httpGet(url);
```

Then I tried to call url into `http://www.google.com:81` which is not reachable. However all calls need to wait that call to fail first, then will be executed.

Anyone can advise how to fix this issue? I know it's deprecated but please ignore it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the fault of `HttpClient`, but `AsyncTask`.

My AsyncTask doesn't allow to be executed simultaneously.

Here is the code to solve it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
else
    task.execute();
```